# How to access the same set of images from 2 projects in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, azure

VS 2013, SQL Server 2012, Entity frame, Web API 2

Both project access the same database

Initially my solution has only one project. This project will read and write images. So I save image path in database and save the image itself in this project's folder "~/Images/".

Later I added another project into this solution. This project also need to read and write the same set of images. When I try to read an image saved by the first project (say "~/Images/xyz.jpg") by first getting image path from database and then access it, I was told the file doesn't exist. Then I realize that I was concatenating the first project's domain name and path "~/Images/xyz.jpg". But actually "~/Images/xyz.jpg" is a path in project 1. So apparently this doesn't exist, I even don't have a "~/Images" folder in the second project.

I am going to deploy these two projects to Azure. So I am not going to configure IIS.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Use blob storage maybe?

Comment: what is blob? I tend to not use this kind of new concepts since I don't have time to learn right now...

Comment: You can also store the image itself in the database. That is if you have time learn how :)

Comment: as I am aware, the most common way to save image in database is saving path in database but save image itself in a file. I didn't research this, but this seems to suggest that store image itself in database have some downside comparing to saving path in database?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use absolute path for getting images. You can introduce a config parameter for your image path (put it in your  in web.config) - for example c:\myprojectname\images. Then save only an image filename into the database. When you are retrieving image filename back, concatenate it with absolute path from config and you will be able to access it.

One things. Make sure to check and create the folder if it does not exist on app start.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that I will deploy both projects to Azure which means I don't know where they save my files. It's not like you deploy to your own server and you can configure your IIS.

Comment: I understand that. But Azure role is basically a Windows Server virtual machine and you can work with filesystem (not a best practice though). If you don't want to get into azure blobs you need to work with the filesystem. Whether you decide to use absolute or relative path - in both cases you may encounter permission issues.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering when I deploy these two projects, how can I know that Azure deploy them to the same virtual machine?

Comment: You can configure your azure service definition to keep both apps on the same Web Role. Check [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg433110.aspx) and [link](http://www.wou.edu/~rvitolo06/WATK/Labs/AdvancedWebAndWorkerRoles/Lab.html/html/DocSet_307d8ff3-1c99-446c-a326-a58cf9cb38be.html). But you won't be able to scale your Web Role horizontally (create multiple instances). I'd highly recommend learn about azure blobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How does blob comparing to save image itself in db? What's your suggestion? Azure blob subscription have additional cost.

Comment: The purpose of blob storage itself is to keep large object (files). I would not recommend keep files in the database because Azure Database storage is much more _expensive_ and _limited_ than blob storage [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) and [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/). Azure storage cost shouldn't be significant in comparison with Web Role or DB costs, but of course it depends on amount of images you are going to store.

Comment: Thank you very much. I researched a little bit yesterday and learned that Azure storage is the way to store images, so that multiple instance can access the same images.